# Is PCA possible in 2x2 matrix taken from 3x3 population covariance matrix

Tags: r, pca, eigenvector, covariance-matrix

Population matrix is given as below:

[image]

May I know if I want only first two Principal Components, PC1 and PC2, can I make the matrix as 2x2 matrix below to perform calculation of eigen vectors?

[image]

Comment: You need to run the PCA on the whole matrix because PC1 & PC2 are a combination of the matrix values which are reordered and not in original form. Once the PCA is completed you can then subset (or return only) the first two components.

Comment: @sconfluentus yes..I got it now.. Thanks for the clarification :)